# Выход из цикла по нажатие ESC в Си

Tags: c, input

Можете помочь решить проблему. Я пыталась написать программу которая пишет где парные и непарные числа и выход из неё когда нажимаю ESC. Я пересмотрела много вариаций кода но так и не получилось сделать выход при нажатие ESC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y, z = 1;
    char esc;


    for(;;){
        if(!esc == 27){
            break;
        }
        else{
        printf("\nVvedite chislo ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(x % 2 != 0){
            printf("\nVu vveli ne parne chislo - %d", x);
        }
        else printf("\nVu vveli parne chislo - %d . Vvedite ne parne!", x);

        }
        }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эти числа называются "чётные" и "нечётные". Вы где-нибудь присваиваете значение переменной `esc`? Отож.

Comment: Извините меня, я из Украины и забыла как будет на русском

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно, но тогда надо считывать все символы, руками их составлять в числа... Все очень сложно для начинающего, поверьте. Лучше сделать окончание работы при вводе, например, 0:

```
printf("\nVvedite chislo, 0 dlya vykhoda: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
if (x == 0) break;
if(x % 2 != 0){
```